# OS X application that can run shell commands

Tags: objective-c, macos, shell, file-association

I tried asking this question on [Apple.StackExchange.com](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/149097/osx-application-that-can-run-shell-scripts), but they redirected me back to here.

I created a custom `file association` with `TextEdit` and have it working. I need to now build an application that uses my custom `file association` and runs `shell commands` to open non proprietary applications (like TextEdit, VLC, ect). This application will be downloaded from the web.

How can I achieve all of this? It can be in any language, but preferable `Objective-C`

Comment: Have you checked the `open <your_cusom_assosiated_file>` shell command ?
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/open.1.html

Comment: @deimus Yes that command works perfect. I need to build an application that can run that command. I couldn't find a way for Cocoa apps to run shell commands like that. The application needs to stay open till the user closes it because I will be performing other logic as well.

Comment: adding an answer, check there

Comment: I don't think SO is the right place for asking THIS BROAD a question -- i mean: do you want us to write the app for you? ;)

Comment: @Daij-Djan You are correct on the vagueness of the question. Hence why I asked it on Apple SE first, but they said to come here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like there is a better way to do it

```
[[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] openFile:@"<FULL_PATH_TO_YOUR_ASSOSIATED_FILE>"];
```

From the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSWorkspace_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSWorkspace/openFile:) for `openFile`

> Opens the specified file specified using the default app associated
>   with its type.

---

Less elegant way to do the same is following :

Check the location of the `open` command on your system like `whereis open` and use the found location for the executable to replace in the code below

```
NSTask *task = [[NSTask alloc] init];
[task setLaunchPath:@"<FULL_PATH_TO_OPEN_COMMAND>"];
[task setArguments:@[ @"<FULL_PATH_TO_YOUR_ASSOSIATED_FILE>"]];
[task launch];
```

Comment: the task is way more elegant as that way the app can easily monitor it / keep alive while it is alive - the op wants to keep running as long as scripts are running

Comment: I can use NSTask run my shell script then I'm using NSWorkspace to monitor the application running. Thanks!